# Why 1st condition doesn`t work?

Tags: jquery, api, if-statement

ok so i want to get random quote(s) through API(forismatic.com) and if it have 140 letters share via tweeter.my question is, because i not sure,why 1st condition doesn`t work.

```
var tweetLink = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";
var quoteUrl = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=867576&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?";
function getQuote() {
$.getJSON(quoteUrl, createTweet);
}
function createTweet(input) {
if (tweetText.length > 140) {
getQuote();}


var tweetText = "Quote of the day - " + input.quoteText + " Author: " +   input.quoteAuthor;}
     if (!input.quoteAuthor.length) {
    input.quoteAuthor = "Unknown author";

 else {
var tweet = tweetLink + encodeURIComponent(tweetText);
$('.quote').text(input.quoteText);
$('.author').text("Author: " + input.quoteAuthor);
$('.tweet').attr('href', tweet);
}
}
  $(document).ready(function() {
getQuote();
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    getQuote();
})
});
```

Comment: You forgot the part where you describe a problem and ask a question about that problem.  As for a "code review", the first suggestion would be to sensibly format your code.

Comment: ok sorry, i am fresh.i corrected i hope its more clear now

Comment: Your edit didn't add any information to the question, so no it didn't clarify anything.  So... You have one version which "works" and one version which "get error" and you're asking which of the two to use?  I suspect the one which works would be preferable.  If you're trying to ask something more specific, you haven't asked it or described anything about it in the question.

Comment: I also don't understand the question. You seem to be calling `getQuote()` in lots of different places, is that correct?

Comment: If you put that statement first you get an error because it's before you assigned to `tweetText`.

Comment: I changed the question and conditions order.I am learning for couple weeks and i try to understand js/jquery (basics). I was thinking statement saying about number of letters (140) should be first... just trying to understand basic logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you say that this condition "doesn't work"?:

```
if (tweetText.length > 140) {
```

Surely your browser's debugging console is telling you the problem here.  The `tweetText` variable is undefined here.  Because you define it *after* you use it:

```
if (tweetText.length > 140) {
    getQuote();
}
var tweetText = "Quote of the day - " + input.quoteText + " Author: " + input.quoteAuthor;
```

To put it simply, you can't *use* a value before you *have* a value.  Surely you meant to put those two operations in the opposite order:

```
var tweetText = "Quote of the day - " + input.quoteText + " Author: " + input.quoteAuthor;
if (tweetText.length > 140) {
    getQuote();
}
```

First define the variable, *then* use the variable.

Note that there *might* be other errors in your code, but it's *very* difficult to tell just from looking at it unless you structure the code more sensibly.  Keep in mind that code isn't meant to only *execute*, it's also meant to *be read and understood by humans*.  That includes you.  Code which you can read and understand will be *far* easier to debug.